# What is the meaning of this sentence which I found?

Tags: meaning

[Source](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0469494/synopsis)

> [...]: he claims he does all the work himself, only hires men he can trust to complete the work and will eliminate the need for a "contractor", **a middleman of sorts that will collect more money from the community that Daniel believes should go back to the landowners themselves**.

I didn't understand from: a middleman of sorts & remaining sentence

What is the meaning of this sentence which I found ?

Answer (score 1):

*"a middleman of sorts that will collect more money from the community that Daniel believes should go back to the landowners themselves"* is a noun phrase. It's additional information about the "contractor". You may parse it like this:

> [ a middleman of sorts ] [ that will collect [ [ more money from the community ] [ that ( Daniel believes ) should go back to the landowners themselves. ]

This can be broken down into two subordinate clauses:

1. A "middleman [of sorts](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/of-sorts)" who will collect more money from the community.
2. Daniel believes that this "more money from the community" should go back to the landowners themselves.

The meaning should be clear enough now.